# Pre-constructor initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

My problem is like this, I have a class named "Product" and another class named "Agriculture", the "Agriculture" class is inheriting the "Product" class.

When I summon the "Agriculture" constructor obviously the "Product" constructor is summoned first.

The question is, can I initialize one of the product's members via a set method first?

Comment: Nope, but you can change the value from your Agriculture constructor.  Or consider adding parameters to Product's constructor so you can pass in the correct initial values.

Comment: The question is rather obscure. Please care to clarify it with an appropriate coding example (in other words, **show your code**).

Comment: Sure you can.  Use the constructor in Agriculture to make the appropriate calls to your Product parent.

Comment: I think you would benefit from showing what you want to do with some code.

Comment: Nope. Also why would you want to. Note: Virtual functions will not work corrrectly until all the constructs have finished executing so you have no access to derived class members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have:

```
class Product { ... };
class Agriculture : public Product { ...};
```

you can't escape the standard rule that the base object is constructed before the derived object.  You have no chance to intervene in this order, nor set anything in `Product` before it's constructor starts.

**Recommendation:**

The best design for your need would be to foresee a `Product` constructor that takes as additional parameter(s) the value(s) that you want to set:

```
 class Product {
     string origin; 
 public:  
     Product () : origin("tbd") { } 
     Product (string withorigin) { ...}
     void setOrigin (string myorigin) { origin=myorigin; }  
 };
 class Agriculture : public Product {
 public: 
     Agriculture () : Product ("Earth") { ...} 
 };
```

**Workaround:**

If such design would not fit your needs, the only thing you could imagine, would be to have a static member in `Product`.  This member would then be independent of any `Product`, and could thus be set before an object is constructed.

```
 class Product {
     static string defaultCurrency; 
     string currency;
 public:  
     Product () : currency(defaultCurrency) { ... } 
     static void setDefaultCurrency (string cur) { defaultCurrency=cur; }  
 };
 class Agriculture : public Product { ...  };

 int main() {
     Product::setDefaultCurrency("EUR"); 
     Agriculture a1; 
 }
```

It's more error prone: the construction result depends on order of operations not related to the construction.  This could be a problem for example in case of multithreading, if several threads construct objects at same moment.

Comment: I have many types of products (Agriculture,Diary, etc..) and I want that whenever I construct a type of product, for example an agriculture I want the product's constructor to act differently for each type, can I at least do that?

Comment: @AssafKaravani make two constructors

Comment: I used your recommendation and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AssafKaravani  I could imagine that you use my recommendation (i.e. a second constructor, as highlighted by *user3528438*) using an enum parameter indicating what kind of family of products you construct.  This answers your need and uses an acceptable way.  However this introduces a dependency of the base class to its derived which is not a good design practice either.  You should post another question with some more code and describing what is so different between your Product constructions.  Perhaps there's another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Product constructor is called firstly, and you set some values inside this constructor. So why you still want to initialize one of the product's members via a set method first?

Comment: If you want to " I want that whenever I construct a type of product, for example an agriculture I want the product's constructor to act differently for each type", you can define a virtual function in Product, then implement different versions to set values in each derived class

Comment: Note: You can **NOT** call virtual methods during construction.